# What does the 's' of Twilio API's sid stand for?

Tags: twilio-api

In `Twilio's API` docs, sid is frequently used, for example, workflowSid.

Does the `sid` means secure id or not?

I did some search with no obvious answer.

Could anyone please point out what does `sid` means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer documentation says it stands for "String Identifier":

https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-sid

(This was bugging me too. It's not mnemonically helpful to see an acronym everywhere without a sensible meaning of what it is)

"String ID" will have to do!

Answer (score 0):

After Searching their documents a while ago because I was Looking For the same thing, SID Stands for "Security IDentifier"

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134387-What-is-a-Message-SID-

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Could you please provide an official doc describing it?

Answer (score -1):

In Twilio App, SID means an unique identifier given for an account along with token to verify account details when executing an API, 's' here can be taken as 'sender'. SID can be taken as sender id.

'S' here can be taken as 'sender' or 'secure' or 'specific' or 'service'.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response, : )

I think your answer make sense, but could you please provide some official page confirming this?